# Except from memory and CPU leaks, what will be reasons for Node.js server might go went down?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js (Express.js) server for my React.js website as BFF. I use Node.js for SSR, proxying some request and cache some pages in Redis. In last time I found that my server time to time went down. I suggest an uptime is about 2 days. After restart, all ok, then response time growth from hour to hour. I have resource monitoring at this server, and I see that server don't have problems with RAM or CPU. It used about 30% of RAM and 20% of CPU.

I regret to say it's a big production site and I can't make minimal reproducible example, cause i don't know where  is reason of these error :(

Except are memory and CPU leaks, what will be reasons for Node.js server might go went down?

I need at least direction to search.

#### UPDATE1:

"went down" - its when kubernetes kills container due 3 failed life checks  (GET request to a root / of website)

My site don't use any BD connection but call lots of 3rd party API's. About 6 API requests due one GET/ request from browser

#### UPDATE2:

Thx. To your answers, guys.
To understand what happend inside my GET/ request, i'm add open-telemetry into my server. In longtime and timeout GET/ requests i saw long API requests with very big **tcp.connect** and **tls.connect**.

[image]

I think it happens due lack of connections or something about that. I think Mostafa Nazari is right.
I create patch and apply them within the next couple of days, and then will say if problem gone

### I solve problem.

It really was lack of connections. I add reusing node-fetch connection due keepAlive and a lot of cache for saving connections. And its works.

Thanks for all your answers. They all right, but most helpful thing was added open-telemetry to my server to understand what exactly happens inside request.

For other people with these problems, I'm strongly recommended as first step, add telemetry to your project.

https://opentelemetry.io/

PS: i can't mark two replies as answer. Joe have most detailed and Mostafa Nazari most relevant to my problem. They both may be "best answers".

Tnx for help, guys.

Comment: Possibilities: 1) Memory leak, leading to steadily increasing memory usage and eventually running out. 2) File handle leak (not closing a file handle) leading to eventually exhausting the process limit for file handles.  3) Database resource leak leading to leaking some database resource and eventually running out causing an error that isn't handled properly causing crash, 4) Some other kind of resource leak (depends upon what your program is doing).

Comment: If the server is slowing down over time before it crashes, then you can insert some performance measuring logging/metrics to identify exactly which operations are starting to get slower and slower and that will likely offer clues as to where to look next. Repeat implementing more logging and more metrics in narrower areas until you narrow down where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @jfriend00 thx. I try to do in this direction. Yesterday i added opentelemetry tracing in GET/ route and now i'm waiting a results.

Comment: an uncaught or unhandled error will crash it, right?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston nope. Kubernetis kill them due to long timeouts.

Comment: "go went down" (sic) is not a specific enough description of the symptom.  What do you mean by that?  Is the only symptom that a client can't connect? Or perhaps that a client can connect but not get a response?  Did the node process exit?  Did it become unresponsive?

Comment: @Wyck kubernetes kill them due 3 failed life checks. In this container life check is GET request to site root.

Comment: Kubernetes is not node. The question looks like it's about node.

Comment: K8s stops pod with node.js server due a request timeout for node.js, i thinks its about node.js actually

Comment: So the question is not, "why did the server go down?"  You *know* that: K8s stopped it.  The question is "why did the server become unresponsive?" or more specifically, "Why did it fail its life check, which is a specific GET request?"  You'll need to provide a way to reproduce the problem for us to answer that.  But there could be any number of reasons that a GET doesn't return a result in a timely manner - depending on the complexity of what is performed during the request.

Comment: @KonstantinPershin the node server is not stopping/exit but if it is you can debug it using this event -->https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-beforeexit
Other than that i feel you need to debug the /GET route there are high chances that your /GET route is not returning something and the reason could be erroneous code, some depreciation or up-gradation from the Third-party APIs. Can you please share the code for /GET route

Comment: One possibility is that the server is getting stuck in an infinite loop or taking too long to complete a request, causing the liveness check to fail. Another possibility is that there are issues with the third-party APIs that your server is communicating with. These issues could include timeouts, rate limiting, or the APIs being down.

Comment: tnx. As first step I add into my server opentellemetry tracing to understand what happened inside GET/

Comment: My best bet is your API calls to third-party places leak sockets, when there is network timeout somewhere. Just guessing.

Comment: You can use the node-clinic suite of tools to try to understand what's going on. In particular the `clinic doctor` command. See here how you can use it https://youtu.be/KvVCafGmrWA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradual growth of response time suggest some kind of leak.
If CPU and memory consumption is excluded, another potentially limiting resources include:

1. File descriptors - when your server forgets to close files. Monitor for number of files in /proc//fd/* to confirm this. See what those files are, find which code misbehaves.
2. Directory listing - even temporary directory holding a lot of files will take some time to scan, and if your application is not removing some temporary files and lists them - you will be in trouble quickly.
3. Zombie processes - just monitor total number of processes on the server.
4. Firewall rules (some docker network magic may in theory cause this on host system) - monitor length of output of "iptables -L" or "iptables-save" or equivalent on modern kernels. Rare condition.
5. Memory fragmentation - this may happen in languages with garbage collection, but often leaves traces with something like "Can not allocate memory" in logs. Rare condition, hard to fix. Export some health metrics and make your k8s restart your pod preemptively.
6. Application bugs/implementation problems. This really depends on internal logic - what is going on inside the app. There may be some data structure that gets filled in with data as time goes by in some tricky way, becoming O(N) instead of O(1). Really hard to trace down, unless you have managed to reproduce the condition in lab/test environment.
7. API calls from frontend shift to shorter, but more CPU-hungry ones. Monitor distribution of API call types over time.

Comment: your answer sounds complete, I suggest you adding row 8: Virtual Machine Freeze: when there is a heavy I/O load on VM host, you may experience a freeze situation on VM instances. if it takes too long (several minutes) then some of your processes might not work properly

Comment: You right in general, vm freeze can be an issue. In particular - author mentions in the comments that his kubernetes kills this particular pod, so most probably vm is healthy, if exists at all here.

Answer (score 2):

With any incoming/outgoing web requests, 2 File Descriptors will be acquired. as there is a limit on number of FDs, OS does not let new Socket to be opened, this situation cause "Timeout Error" on clients. you can easily check number of open FDs by `sudo ls -la /proc/_PID_/fd/ | tail -n +4 | wc -l` where `_PID_` is nodejs PID, if this value is rising, you have connection leak issue.

I guess you need to do the following to prevent Connection Leak:

1. make sure you are closing outgoing API call Http Connection (it depends on how you are opening them, some libraries manage this and you just need to config them)
2. cache your outgoing API call (if it is possible) to reduce API call
3. for your outgoing API call, use Connection pool, this would manage number of open HttpConnection, reuse already-opened connection and ...
4. review your code, so that you can serve a request faster than now (for example make your API call more parallel instead of await or nested call). anything you do to make your response faster, is good for preventing this situation

Comment: i think you right in my case. To understand what happens inside my GET/ request i'm add open telemetry to my server and saw this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1KCL.png

Its really lack of connections. Maybe by case you show.

Comment: 3 seconds for TCP connection establishment is really tooo much(normally its <200ms) after all I said, there can be a network-issue (either from your host or any third-party host or client). to make sure and find where the problem is, you can implement a PING api, which does nothing and returns a low-byte data (`ok` message), and disable other APIs, then make a burst test and measure time, if latency is still exists, you should check client-server network with your ISP and Host, if no, try to add third-party API calls one by one, and find the slow network.latency always led to Denial of Service

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the many possibilities of why your server may go down:

- **Memory leaks** The server may eventually fail if a Node.js application is leaking memory, as you stated in your post above. This may occur if the application keeps adding new objects to the memory without appropriately cleaning up.
- **Unhandled exceptions** The server may crash if an exception is thrown in the application code and is not caught. To avoid this from happening, ensure that all exceptions are handled properly.
- **Third-party libraries** If the application uses any third-party libraries, the server may experience problems as a result. Before using them, consider examining their resource usage, versions, or updates.
- **Network Connection** The server's network connection may have issues if the server is sending a lot of queries to third-party APIs or if the connection is unstable. Verify that the server is handling connections, timeouts, and retries appropriately.
- **Connection to the Database** Even though your server doesn't use any BD connections, it's a good idea to look for any stale connections to databases that could be problematic.
- **High Volumes of Traffic** The server may experience performance issues if it is receiving a lot of traffic. Make sure the server is set up appropriately to handle a lot of traffic, making use of load balancing, caching, and other speed enhancement methods. Cloudflare is always a good option ;)
- **Concurrent Requests** Performance problems may arise if the server is managing a lot of concurrent requests. Check to see if the server is set up correctly to handle several requests at once, using tools like a connection pool, a thread pool, or other concurrency management strategies.

(Credit goes to my System Analysis and Design course slides)

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem. It really was lack of connections. I add reusing node-fetch connection due keepAlive and a lot of cache for saving connections. And its works.

Thanks for all your answers. They all right, but most helpful thing was added open-telemetry to my server to understand what exactly happens inside request.

For other people with these problems, I'm strongly recommended as first step, add telemetry to your project.

https://opentelemetry.io/